# How do I make the repository search run within the topic?

Tags: c#, github-api, octokit.net

The code to search for "github.com" repositories:

```
public async void searchReposit_GitHub()        
{   
    var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("my-cool-app")); 
    var basicAuth = new Credentials("username", "password"); 

    client.Credentials = basicAuth;

    var request = new SearchRepositoriesRequest("mvc client side framework") 
    {   
        // or go all out and search the readme, name or description?
        In = new[] { InQualifier.Readme, InQualifier.Description, InQualifier.Name },             
    };            

    var result = await client.Search.SearchRepo(request);

    for (int s = 0; s < 3; s++)
    {
        var vr = result.Items[s];

        string readme_content;
        string readme_name;
        string readme_descript;
        string readme_Html_url;

        readme_name = vr.Name;
        readme_descript = vr.Description;
        readme_Html_url = vr.HtmlUrl; 

        try
        {
            var readme = await client.Repository.Content.GetReadme(vr.Id);
            var rawText = readme.Content;

            readme_content = rawText.ToString();

            richTextBox1.AppendText(
                " Сontent `readme` *** " + readme_content + " *** \r\n"); 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(
                " Сontent `readme` -  empty ххх" +  " \r\n"); // url
            // return;
            // throw;
        }                   
    }
}
```

There is a theme [github.com/topics/chrome-extensions](https://github.com/topics/chrome-extensions)

**Question**
How to make the code look inside [github.com/topics/chrome-extensions](https://github.com/topics/chrome-extensions)?

I will add.
"Chrome extension" ([github.com/topics/chrome-extensions](https://github.com/topics/chrome-extensions)) contains 95 pieces of repositories.

How do I search for the words I need in "README.MD" in 95 pieces of repositories that contain the "Chrome extension" [github.com/topics/chrome-extensions](https://github.com/topics/chrome-extensions)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not look like Octokit.NET currently supports topics at all. So there doesn't appear to be a nice & simple way.

But, there is a way... Access to topics via the API is currently available as a preview only. See [List all topics for a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-all-topics-for-a-repository) and especially note the warnings & limitations of the preview.

So you can construct the HTTP request yourself like this:

```
private static async Task<Topics> GetTopics(string repoFullName)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.github.mercy-preview+json"));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(
                Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                    string.Format("{0}:{1}", "username", "password"))));

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "my-cool-app");

    var stringTask = client.GetStringAsync(
        $"https://api.github.com/repos/{repoFullName}/topics");

    var response = await stringTask;

    var topics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Topics>(response);

    return topics;
}
```

I am using the [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library to deserialize the response and my `Topics` class looks like this:

```
public class Topics
{
    public List<string> names { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your loop you can use like this:

```
var topics = await GetTopics(vr.FullName);

if (!topics.names.Contains("chrome-extensions"))
{
     continue;
}
```

You may also want to check for the singular topic [`chrome-extension`](https://github.com/topics/chrome-extension). It seems it's more commonly used as there is currently over 3000 repositories in that one!

Comment: This is being worked on in https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/pull/1720